# checking values before submitting form

Tags: javascript

Before I submit a form I want to check the values in the input.

Here I'm checking if a value is NOt equal to .5 or 1. or not a empty string.

```
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    var ftimes = document.getElementsByClassName("add_timebox");
    var fflag = 0;
    for(i=0;i< ftimes.length;i++) {
        var value1 = ftimes[i].value;
       console.log(value1);
        if ( value1 !==.5 ||value1 !== 1  || (!IsStringEmpty(value1)) ){

            fflag = 1;
            console.log('inside');
        }

}
if(fflag==1) {
    alert('enter again' );
    return false;
}
```

I have made many changes to the IF statement to try to get it correct.
But it is still going in the loop even when I know if shouldn't.

For example when i submit the form and i have one input value equal .22
then it should only give me 1 'inside' but in keeps repeating:

inside
.22
(empty string)
inside 
....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show how you are implementing your *IsStringEmpty* method, but if you are using something like this, then any number is also a non-empty string, so your if statement will always run.

```
function IsStringEmpty(str) {
  return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

So you need to change your ORs with ANDs, or it will never check the number conditions.

You can check if the value is not an empty string and is different from 0.5 and 1. Then your condition should be like this.

```
if (!IsStringEmpty(value1) && value1 !== 0.5 && value1 !== 1)
```

But, you are getting the value from a form, so it will be a string. Therefore, you are comparing strings and you need this.

```
if (!IsStringEmpty(value1) && value1 !== ".5" && value1 !== "1")
```

Although you will probably want to compare floats, in which case you need this.

```
if (!IsStringEmpty(value1) && parseFloat(value1) !== .5 && parseFloat(value1) !== 1))
```

So basically, when you enter 1, .5 or and empty string in all of the form fields, you skip the inside block. But if you have any other value in any of the fields, then the flag will be set to 1. If that is not what you meant, please update your question to be more specific.

Please check Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/5x1G6248dPYXEhpBYxPX).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i actually meant NOT =.5 and 1

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a break; statment in your if condition once the if condition is satisfied.

```
if ( value1 !==.5 ||value1 !== 1  || (!IsStringEmpty(value1)) ){

            fflag = 1;
            console.log('inside');
            break;

        }
```

Comment: i dont think the break will do because it wont be able to show the alert

Comment: It will definitely show the alert because the break is only breaking the for loop but not the later if condition. But if you want your form not to submit after showing alert then add the below statement.

if(fflag==1) {
    alert('enter again' );
    event.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}

Comment: i see, but the problem is that is going inside the IF condition no matter what the value is